# pgfgantt- Adding a number line on top of gantt chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

How do you add a number line on top of a gantt chart as in the picture below?
MWE added.

```
\documentclass[ ]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\definecolor{foobarblue}{RGB}{0,153,255}
\newganttchartelement{foobar}{
foobar/.style={
shape=rectangle,
inner sep=0pt,
draw=foobarblue!50!black,
very thick,
fill=white}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid,
inline,
progress label text=\relax,
]{1}{15}
\ganttfoobar{Bar 1}{1}{3} \\
\ganttfoobar{Bar 2}{3}{7} \\
\ganttfoobar{Bar 3}{9}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use regular Ti*k*Z commands inside the `ganttchart` environment. Just note that the base unit for the x-axis is 0.5cm by default:

```
\documentclass[ ]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\definecolor{foobarblue}{RGB}{0,153,255}
\newganttchartelement{foobar}{
    foobar/.style={
        shape=rectangle,
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=foobarblue!50!black,
        very thick,
        fill=white
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    inline,
    progress label text=\relax,
]{1}{15}
\ganttfoobar{Bar 1}{1}{3} \\
\ganttfoobar{Bar 2}{3}{7} \\
\ganttfoobar{Bar 3}{9}{12}

\begin{scope}[yshift=0.33cm]
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (7.5,0);
    \draw ([yshift=-3pt]0,0) -- ++([yshift=6pt]0,0) node[above] {0};
    \draw ([yshift=-3pt]1,0) -- ++([yshift=6pt]0,0) node[above] {$x$};
    \draw ([yshift=-3pt]4,0) -- ++([yshift=6pt]0,0) node[above] {$y$};
\end{scope}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]